# PNG Transparency on Canvas

Tags: canvas, png, transparency, alpha, color-channel

Does canvas support PNG alpha? Im having some issues with a few PNGs that I've added to the canvas. The edges of the images are black and jagged as if no alpha channel exists or is being recognized.

Comment: It seems likely that you are saving 8-bit PNGs with 1-bit transparency, and so it's being blended with black. Can you share one of the files that is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a 24-bit PNG with alpha on the canvas it understands it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Maybe your PNGs are not clean, i.e. have non-transparent regions at the borders?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am using the processing.js library to display the image. I just looked at the docs and it doesn't mention that PNG is supported so I guess Im out of luck.

Comment: @Rigil That seems very unlikely.

Comment: @Phrogz it turns out I had the framerate up too high and as I would click it would draw PNGs at 30 frames per second overlapping eachother giving it the jagged edge appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [clearRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) or [fillRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) before redrawing the PNG image, if you are doing it in a requestAnimationFrame or setInterval loop.

I stumbled upon this question as I had a similar problem, but my image was already at 24-bit. Had a requestAnimationFrame loop redrawing the PNG image to the canvas and (as you said) as they overlapped, the result was this "burned" edges where it should have the alpha "fade-out" transparency.

Simply by cleaning the area before calling drawImage, you can prevent that image to be rendered over itself.